# Can't install the GPU Debugging Tools on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have installed all the SDK Tools but when I try to install the Debugging Tools appears this error:

"Packages to install: 
- GPU Debugging tools (extras;android;gapid;3)

Preparing "Install GPU Debugging tools (revision: 3.1.0)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/gapid_2994895_linux.zip
This download could not be finalized from the interim state. Retrying without caching.
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/gapid_2994895_linux.zip
Failed packages:
- GPU Debugging tools (extras;android;gapid;3)"

Also when I try to run the app I have another error: 
"Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] --> The file or directory doesnt exists".

The idea.log shows this:

2020-03-06 07:46:27,537 [  13463]   INFO - ssistant.WhatsNewBundleCreator - Remote WNA config file not found 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/assistant/3.6.1.xml
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1890)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:263)
    at com.android.tools.idea.whatsnew.assistant.WhatsNewBundleCreator.downloadConfig(WhatsNewBundleCreator.java:250)
    at com.android.tools.idea.whatsnew.assistant.WhatsNewBundleCreator.updateConfig(WhatsNewBundleCreator.java:238)
    at com.android.tools.idea.whatsnew.assistant.WhatsNewBundleCreator.isNewConfigVersion(WhatsNewBundleCreator.java:161)
    at com.android.tools.idea.whatsnew.assistant.WhatsNewCheckVersionTask.run(WhatsNewCheckVersionTask.kt:34)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:894)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:169)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:591)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:537)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:156)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.run(CoreProgressManager.java:408)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: My version of Android Studio --> Android Studio 3.6.1